# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'UInt32'

Tags: ios, swift

I was creating a very simple game (guess the number) and when I write:

```
if numberTextField.text == randomNumber {
```

it shows the error:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'UInt32'

Here's what I've written to be clear:

```
@IBAction func guessPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(11)
    if numbertextField.text == randomNumber {
        resultLabel.text = "التخمين صحيح"
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Convert *the contents* of the text field to an integer, and compare that to `randomNumber`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Swift+binary+operator+cannot+be+applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the `textField` contains a **valid number** first before converting it to an `Int`. You can do it like how it's shown below.

```
@IBAction func guessPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(11)
    if let validNumber = Int(textField.text!), validNumber == randomNumber {
        resultLabel.text = "التخمين صحيح"
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this to be shorter and use only one `if` statement

Comment: In case if `textField.text` is `nil` you gonna crash the app, it would be better to unwrap it safely, in the same `if let` you already have.

Comment: @user28434 it’ll always return atleast an empty string, which is not nil.

Comment: @user28434 even if you set the text property to nil right before checking it won't return nil it will return `""`

Comment: @LeoDabus, interesting, it has `null_resettable` in Objective C code, which is weirdest optionality attribute.

Comment: @user28434 I think the reason they keep this property optional is to allow you to assign an optional string to it without the need to unwrap it

Comment: @LeoDabus, that still looks wacky. [This article](https://medium.com/@thanyalukj/nullability-keywords-and-interoperability-between-objective-c-and-swift-220338af958b) states that this attribute is used to allow to set `nil` to get default value. In case of `tintColor`(like in example)  it makes sense, because it is computed using parent's `tintColor`(or parent's parent,  etc) in case of `nil`/default. In case of `text` — it doesn't. If default value is always `""`.